# Get time stamp from cmsg can be NULL?

Tags: c, linux, udp, timespec

I looking at this code
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6.7/source/Documentation/networking/timestamping/timestamping.c#L181

This code try to print the timestamp of packet using `struct timespec *stamp = (struct timespec *)CMSG_DATA(cmsg);`

If this is UDP packet.
Is there any way that `CMSG_DATA(cmsg)` will return NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the definition of [CMSG_DATA](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6.7/source/include/linux/socket.h#L95) you see

```c
#define CMSG_DATA(cmsg) ((void *)((char *)(cmsg) + CMSG_ALIGN(sizeof(struct cmsghdr))))
```

This adds an offset to `cmsg`.
Unless you manage to feed a `cmsg` into that macro that evaluates to `NULL` after adding that offset, the result can never be come `NULL`.